# PHP: _POST and CSS, how to show an active link

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, css

I have a site I'm building in PHP, and have a page that loads data dynamically from mySQL. It uses list items that the user clicks on, causing a _POST to the database, thus not allowing me to customize the CSS of the page they're now seeing. I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically set the css class of the `<li>` they've clicked, as to highlight it. Problem is, if they press another list item, I have to un-highlight the old one. Anyone have input on the best way to go about this?

Comment: Are you saying clicking the list item sends a post request via AJAX and you want to highlight only one list item at a time when clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're submitting the POST requests via AJAX, add something like this (I'm going to assume you've already got the AJAX part out of the way)

```
// var context is a previously identified container for the list items

var items = context.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        // do AJAX stuff

        // remove the "highlight" class from all list items
        for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
            var classname = items[j].className;
            items[j].className = classname.replace(/\bhighlight-class-name\b/i, '');
        }

        // set the "highlight" class on the clicked item
        this.className += ' highlight-class-name';
    }, false);
}
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/jYdMB/

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using Ajax. A JS script would do this. Here is how I will attempt this in JS

- create lis with a unique ids
- use jquery/prototype/xyz toolkit to bind a click event to these lis
- as soon as click is received I look at the event target and try to set or reset a class name on it

For further reading I will suggest this example in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery answer: http://jsfiddle.net/qYUAz/

```
<style type="text/css">
#myNav .active{ 
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>


<ul id="myNav">
    <li><a href="#1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myNav a').click(function(){
    $('#myNav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');    
});
</script>
```